# can we set password for zip file using minizip

Tags: c++, zip, zlib

I want to set password for zip files using minizip.I didn't find an documentation regarding this.I know we can encrypt all the zipped file.

Answer (score 2):

A complete example using C code is provided in the /contrib/minizip directory: minizip.c for the compression, miniunzip.c for the decompression.
As said in the previous comment zipOpenNewFileInZip3 is for compression with password.
For decompression you have to open the zipped file(s) with unzOpenCurrentFilePassword.

Answer (score 1):

Googling:

```
err = zipOpenNewFileInZip3_64(zf,savefilenameinzip,&zi,
                                 NULL,0,NULL,0,NULL /* comment*/,
                                 (opt_compress_level != 0) ? Z_DEFLATED : 0,
                                 opt_compress_level,0,
                                 /* -MAX_WBITS, DEF_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY, */
                                 -MAX_WBITS, DEF_MEM_LEVEL, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY,
                                 password,crcFile, zip64);
```

Taken from [**here**](http://code.google.com/p/microzip/source/browse/minizip/demos/minizip.c?r=3d42842facdc17d1bdb1c0443d3f5479ab9e2c6d).

If you use from command line:

```
minizip [-p password]
```

Comment: i think this password is to encrypt file (i.e inside zipped folder)

Comment: otherwise you have to use 7zip that surely provide encryption